# Longest match only with Spacy Phrasematcher

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have created a [Spacy Phrasematcher](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher) to match names in a document, following the [tutorial](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#phrasematcher). I want to use the resulting matches as additional training data in order to train a Spacy NER model.
My patterns, however, contain both full names (e.g. 'Barack Obama') and last names ('Obama') separately.

Hence, in a sentence that contains 'Barack Obama', both patterns match, resulting in overlapping matches. This overlap, however, triggers an exception when I try to use the data for training, e.g.:

```
ValueError: [E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: '(19, 33, 'PERSON')' and '(29, 33, 'PERSON')'. A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap.
```

I've been considering to filter out overlapping matches before using the data for training, but this seems like a very inefficient approach, resulting in a significant increase in processing time for large data.

Is there a way to set up a `PhraseMatcher` so that it only matches the longest match for overlapping matches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `PhraseMatcher` doesn't have a built-in way to filter out overlapping matches while it's matching, but there is a utility function to filter overlapping matches afterwards: `spacy.util.filter_spans()`. It prefers the longest span and if two overlapping spans are the same length, the earlier span in the text.

Comment: Quick question: What do you mean by: 'the earliest span in the text'?

Comment: The span that starts earlier in the text, so if you have overlapping spans from tokens 3-6 and 5-8, it would prefer the one from 3-6.

Comment: Thanks @aab. It is clear now.
So, if two spans have the same length and overlap at the same position, then filter_spans would attached the entity that has been included first in the PhraseMatcher